# Filebeat 5.0 output to Kafka multiple topics

Tags: apache-kafka, filebeat

I installed Filebeat 5.0 on my app server and have 3 Filebeat prospectors, each of the prospector are pointing to different log paths and output to one kafka topic called `myapp_applog` and everything works fine.

**My Filebeat output configuration to one topic - Working**

```
output.kafka:
    # initial brokers for reading cluster metadata
    hosts: ["broker.1.ip.address:9092", "broker.2.ip.address:9092", "broker.3.ip.address:9092"]

    # message topic selection + partitioning
    topic: 'myapp_applog'
    partition.round_robin:
      reachable_only: false

    required_acks: 1
    compression: gzip
    max_message_bytes: 1000000
```

What I want to do is send each of the log files to seperate topics based on a condition see documentation section on [topics](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/kafka-output.html#_topics). I have tried to do it but no data is been sent to any of the topics. Does anyone know why my condition does not match or it is correct. I can seem to find an example on how to correctly use the "topics topic condition".

Here is my kafka output to muliple topics configuration.

**Not Working**

```
output.kafka:
    # initial brokers for reading cluster metadata
    hosts: ["broker.1.ip.address:9092", "broker.2.ip.address:9092", "broker.3.ip.address:9092"]

    # message topic selection + partitioning
    topics:
      - topic: 'myapp_applog'
        when: 
          equals:
            document_type: applog_myappapi
      - topic: 'myapp_applog_stats'
        when:
          equals:
            document_type: applog_myappapi_stats
      - topic: 'myapp_elblog'
        when:
          equals:
            document_type: elblog_myappapi
    partition.round_robin:
      reachable_only: false

    required_acks: 1
    compression: gzip
    max_message_bytes: 1000000
```

Here is full filebeat.yml configuration file.

```
################### Filebeat Configuration Example #########################
############################# Filebeat ######################################
filebeat.prospectors:
    # App logs - prospector
    - input_type: log
      paths:
        - /myapp/logs/myapp.log
      exclude_lines: [".+? INFO[^*].+", ".+? DEBUG[^*].+"]
      exclude_files: [".gz$", ".tmp"]
      fields:
        api: myappapi
        environment: STG
      ignore_older: 24h
      document_type: applog_myappapi
      scan_frequency: 1s

      # Multine on Timestamp, YYYY-MM-DD
      # https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/multiline-examples.html 
      multiline:
        pattern: '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
        negate: true
        match: after
        max_lines: 500
        timeout: 5s

    # Server Stats - prospector
    - input_type: log
      paths:
        - /myapp/logs/serverstats.log

      # Exclude messages with log level
      exclude_lines: [".+? ERROR[^*].+", ".+? DEBUG[^*].+"]
      exclude_files: [".gz$", ".tmp"]
      fields:
        api: myappapi
        environment: STG
      ignore_older: 24h
      document_type: applog_myappapi_stats
      scan_frequency: 1s

    # ELB prospector
    -
      input_type: log
      paths:
        - /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-access_log
      document_type: elblog_myappapi
      fields:
        api: myappapi
        environment: STG
      exclude_lines: [".+? INFO[^*].+", ".+? DEBUG[^*].+"]
      exclude_files: [".gz$", ".tmp"]
      ignore_older: 24h

      # 0s, it is done as often as possible. Default: 10s
      scan_frequency: 1s
registry_file: /var/lib/filebeat/registry

############################# Output ##########################################
# Configure what outputs to use when sending the data collected by the beat.
# Multiple outputs may be used.
#----------------------------- Kafka output --------------------------------

output.kafka:
    # initial brokers for reading cluster metadata
    hosts: ["broker.1.ip.address:9092", "broker.2.ip.address:9092", "broker.3.ip.address:9092"]

    # message topic selection + partitioning
    topics:
      - topic: 'myapp_applog'
        when: 
          equals:
            document_type: applog_myappapi
      - topic: 'myapp_applog_stats'
        when:
          equals:
            document_type: applog_myappapi_stats
      - topic: 'myapp_elblog'
        when:
          equals:
            document_type: elblog_myappapi
    partition.round_robin:
      reachable_only: false

    required_acks: 1
    compression: gzip
    max_message_bytes: 1000000

############################# Logging #########################################

# There are three options for the log ouput: syslog, file, stderr.
# Under Windos systems, the log files are per default sent to the file output,
# under all other system per default to syslog.
logging:

  # Send all logging output to syslog. On Windows default is false, otherwise
  # default is true.
  to_syslog: true

  # Write all logging output to files. Beats automatically rotate files if rotateeverybytes
  # limit is reached.
  to_files: true

  # To enable logging to files, to_files option has to be set to true
  files:
    # The directory where the log files will written to.
    path: /var/log/

    # The name of the files where the logs are written to.
    name: filebeats.log

    # Configure log file size limit. If limit is reached, log file will be
    # automatically rotated
    rotateeverybytes: 10485760 # = 10MB

    # Number of rotated log files to keep. Oldest files will be deleted first.
    keepfiles: 7

  # Enable debug output for selected components. To enable all selectors use ["*"]
  # Other available selectors are beat, publish, service
  # Multiple selectors can be chained.
  #selectors: ["*" ]

  # Sets log level. The default log level is error.
  # Available log levels are: critical, error, warning, info, debug
  level: info
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got the same problem and deal with it by define output as:

```
topics:
  - topic: '%{[type]}'
use_type: true
```

and as input you only have to set in document_type: kaffka's topic

- input_type: log
  paths:

  - /path/to/log/file
    document_type: "you'r kaffka's topic 1"
- input_type: log
  paths:

  - /path/to/another/log/file

  document_type: "you'r another kaffka's topic 1"

Answer (score 4):

**Input:**

```
- type: log
  fields:
    kafka_topic: "my_topic_1"

- type: log
  fields:
    kafka_topic: "my_topic_2"
```

**Output:**

```
output.kafka:
  hosts: ["mybroker:9092"]
  topic: '%{[fields.kafka_topic]}'
```

Above example shows 2 log inputs and 2 kafka topic outputs